Do AirPods Pro 1 work with iPhone 14 or later?
I'm planning to buy AirPods Pro 1 for testing and experience.
Note: I already went through the AirPods Pro 1 Documentation
for reference.
Before I proceed to buy, I had few questions that I had with respect to AirPods Pro 1 usage:

Does it come with the quick charging case?
Does it support with iPhone 14 or later? As documentation says the iPhone 13 series was the last series to have a support for it.
How good the battery life is?
Are there any other factors that I need to consider before buying AirPods Pro 1?

